# knitr changing my reverse assignment operator -> to <-

Tags: r, knitr

I am having trouble when using "reverse" assignment operators (->) in a knitr .Rnw file. For example, I have the following simple .Rnw file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test>>=
    options(tidy=FALSE, width=50)
    1:5 -> a
@
\end{document}
```

When I use knitr to compile into a pdf, the operator -> has been reversed so the output actually has

```
1:5 <- a
```

in it!

how can I change this?

Answer (score 4):

Make `tidy=FALSE` a knitr chunk option rather than an R option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test,tidy=FALSE>>=
    options(tidy=FALSE, width=50)
    1:5 -> a
@
\end{document}
```

(I don't think `tidy=FALSE` does anything at all in `options()`, but I guess it's harmless ...)

[image]

Comment: yep, just about to say the same thing

Comment: Did you actually try the code?  That was my initial thought as well but when I tried it the code ran as expected but displays in the document with the assignment flipped.

Comment: @Dason all the confusion comes from old packages :) [FAQ 1](http://bit.ly/knitr-faq) is unbeatable! I think both R core and I have fixed such problems, so upgrade R (to 3.0.2) and `update.packages()` if you can.

Comment: @Yihui I guess I'll just have to talk to Mike - I was running on the gs server ;)

Comment: @Dason Ahh, our servers... always years behind... I always install a recent version of R in my Cyfiles drive when I have to test R code there. We have a CRAN mirror for the world, but our own R version is always lagging behind. I'm counting on you for a solution that guarantees us a recent R version regardless if it is Ted or Mike or anyone there :)

Answer (score 3):

For setting `tidy=FALSE` on a chunk-by-chunk basis, Ben's answer has got you covered.

To reset the option globally, use `opts_chunk$set()`, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE)
@

<<test>>=
1:5 -> a
@

\end{document}
```

---

Additionally, [as documented here](http://yihui.name/knitr/options), `tidy.opts` can give you finer-grained control over many aspects of the **knitr**'s (and ultimately `formatR::tidy.source()`'s) tidying behavior. Perhaps unfortunately in this case, while you *can* tell **knitr** not to replace `"="` with `"<-"` (by doing `opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(replace.assign=FALSE))`you cannot use that option to control whether `"->"` is replaced by `"<-"`.

Here's an example that uses `tidy.opts`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(replace.assign=FALSE))
@

<<test>>=
j <- function(x) {  x<-y ## x<-y will be printed on new line, with added inter-token spaces
a = 1:5                  ## will be indented, but "=" won't be replaced

                       } ## closing brace will be moved to start of line
@

\end{document}
```